# "Autos ist meine Leidenschaft" oder "Autos sind meine Leidenschaft"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Welche Variante ist richtig?

> 1. Autos **ist** meine Leidenschaft
> 2. Autos **sind** meine Leidenschaft

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Numerus (Einzahl oder Mehrzahl) und Person (1. Person = ich/wir, 2. Person = du/ihr und 3. Person = er/sie/es/sie) des Prädikats müssen mit Numerus und Person des Subjekts übereinstimmen.

Hier steht das Subjekt in der dritten Person und im Plural, daher muss auch das Verb in der dritten Person und im Plural erscheinen. Also:

> Autos **sind** ...

Ob das, was anstelle der Auslassungszeichen steht, im Singular oder Plural steht, ist völlig egal.

Comment: Heißt das, dass wenn man den Satz umdreht, aus dem "sind" ein "ist" wird?  "Meine Leidenschaft ist Autos."?

Comment: @IgorO. Durch das Umdrehen wird »Meine Leidenschaft« ja nicht automatisch zum Subjekt. Es bleibt weiterhin ein Objekt, das in Nominativ steht (es ist ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ). Das Subjekt kann in deutschen Aussagesätzen ja überall (außer an Position 2, die für das Verb reserviert ist) stehen. In »Meine Leidenschaft sind Autos.« steht das Subjekt am Ende des Satzes. Bei Sätzen, die einen Gleichsetzungsnominativ enthalten, ist es zugegebenermaßen manchmal schwierig, zu erkennen welches Satzglied das Subjekt und welches das Objekt ist.

Comment: Hubert, danke! Das ist in der Tat schwierig zu erkennen. Das Thema muss ich mir genauer anschauen :)

Comment: *"@IgorO. ... Es bleibt weiterhin ein Objekt, das in Nominativ steht"* Hoppla! Autos [wer oder was?] sind meine Leidenschaft [wer oder was?]. Wo ist hier ein Objekt? Anders gesagt, seit wann gibt es Objekte im Nominativ? Das Teil heißt Subjektsprädikativ, denn es steht, sichtbar für alle, nach Kopula, so dass *Leidenschaft* ergo das Prädikatsnomen ist. Cheers!

Comment: @Cheers: Es gibt dafür auch den Ausdruck »Nominativobjekt«, der synonym zu »Subjektsprädikativum« und »Gleichsetzungsnominativ« verwendet wird. Und wenn ein Objekt im Nominativ steht, womit sonst als mit »wer oder was« sollte man danach fragen? Ob es Objekte im Nominativ gibt oder nicht ist lediglich eine Frage der Definition.

Comment: I'm not sure it's quite that simple. For example *Es sind meine Eltern,* it would seem that the subject is *Es* but the verb is still conjugated as plural. In English you conjugate according to what comes before the verb: "Cars are my passion." "My passion is cars." In German though, it seems that with nominative verbs you always use plural if there is any doubt: *Autos sind meine Leidenschaft.* *Meine Leidenschaft sind Autos.* At least that's the pattern I'm seeing; I haven't found a reference yet.

Answer (score 5):

Kurz und Bündig: Die zweite Variante ist richtig. Es muss "sind" heißen, da "Autos" die Pluralform ist. Würde hier der Singular gebraucht, wäre auch "ist" richtig (Das Auto ist meine Leidenschaft).